# Google Custom Search automatic spell checking

Tags: spell-checking, google-search-api, google-custom-search

We're having a problem with the automatic spell checking on queries in the XML results of the Google Custom Search.

Queries which are spelled incorrectly return results with the correct spelling e.g. `socer` becomes `soccer` and returns the correct results. On Google.com there is the option to then search for results on the original query using `nfpr=1` in the query string. However this doesn't work in the Google Custom search, and I've been unable to find any other way to search for the incorrect spelling.

Answer (score -1):

For a standard google search this behavior can be avoided by adding the argument &nfpr=1 to the query url.

For a custom search based on the AJAX API, this unfortunately isn't possible.  The only way I've found is to use javascript to parse the user's query, then use a regular expression to put quotes around each single word that is not yet quoted.  So for example, if the keywords received are

"bmw z4" manual

you would change that to

"bmw z4" "manual"

which has the same effect, except that it disables the auto-correction.  Unfortunately if you want to deal with all the special cases of advanced logical syntax (AND, OR, |, -, etc.), your regexp gets a bit complex.

Myself, I just parse the response from Google to see if this is happening, and if so notify the user how to prevent it (by putting quotes around the offending word(s)).

Comment: The putting of quotes around the words didn't seem to work. Any other ideas?

Comment: Can you provide an example of it not working?  I'm fairly certain that quoted words and phrases are not automatically changed by Google. I actually use this solution in production CSEs.